IntelliJ GraphQL plugin error highlighting not working
I have installed the graphql plugin for IntelliJ (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-graphql written by JetBrains s.r.o.) and it does not appear to be working for me.
I have a folder structure that looks like this :
|-- project
|    |-- frontend 
|    |    +-- myQueryDeclerations.ts
|    |    +-- schema.graphql
|    +-- graphql.config.yml

my graphql.config.yml looks like this :

my schema.graphql looks like this :

my queryDeclarations.ts looks like this :

As you can see the syntax highlighting is not working.

the Query type does not recognise the Post in the schema.graphql
(which is why it is red)
My testQuery in my quest declerations is highlighted red where
"posts" is defined.

does anyone know why this does not work?

Could you please clarify if the approach that we suggested on github helped you to resolve the issue?

yes, the answer from VonC worked. But it was deleted which i dont understand why. His answer is basically based on the Github answer
